# continuous functions and limit existance

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let,  $C\in \mathbb R$ and let

$f(x)= Cx^2+1$ if $x \geq 2$ ,  $f(x)= 10-x$ if $x<2$

for what value of $C$ is $f(x)$ a continuous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint: $f(2) = 4C+1, \displaystyle \lim_{x\to 2^{-}} f(x) = f(2) \to 10-2 = 4C+1$.